# Handling data from ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to send data from modal with ajax
This is how i am trying to process it, but it doesnt do anything, if i comment out the first IF block then i can get to $_POST['id'] variable, otherwise it doesnt work.

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['id']) && isset($_SESSION['user'])){
    $sql = "INSERT INTO cart (user_id, id_p, quantity) VALUES(?, ?, ?)";
    $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bind_param('sss', $_SESSION['user'], $_REQUEST['id'], $_REQUEST['quantity'] );
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->close();
}


/*
    @@@@
        -process product ID that we send from modal via AJAX
        -store it in 2D array
    @@@@
*/

if(!isset($_SESSION['cart'])){
    $_SESSION['cart'] = array();
}

if(isset($_POST['id'])){
    $_SESSION['cart'][] = $_POST['id'];
}

?>
```

Here is how i am sending data with ajax, i can see them both with inspect in header but i cant seem to access them.

```
$(document).on('click','.add-to-basket',function(){
    var productID = $('#itemBox').data('id');//Variable for product ID
    var productQ = document.getElementById("quantity").value;//Variable for product Q

    // skryty input do ktere si zapsal ID produktu po otevreni modalu
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        cache: false,
        data: {id : productID, quantity: productQ},
        url: 'cart/includes/cartid.php', // tomuto souboru predas idecko produktu, zapises do kosiku atd.
        success: function(data) {
            window.location.replace("/shop/cart/cart.php")
            alert("Product was added to basket");
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Does your query execute?

Comment: No it doesnt, that php file looks like it doesnt do anything when i left the DB part in it.

Comment: The query execution and "doesn't do anything" are different things. The query might be executed but not insert anything. So - does your query execute?

Comment: Oh nevermind, it is working now, idk what happend i didnt change anything. But thanks for help :)

Answer (score 0):

First you should Print "$_REQUEST" and see what you get and I think you will get your data after that check you have "user" field in your session. The session "user" could be your problem.

Comment: It looks like its working... but i also tried to print some variables but when i try to see response in chrome dev tools it just say "Failed to load response data"

Comment: I think instead of using chrome you should use mozila firefox and install it's add on "firebug" and then you will know what the real problem is.